# Function body not being executed in Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

So I have the following composable function:

```kotlin
@Composable
fun SearchResult() {
    if (searchInput.isNotEmpty()) {
        Column() {
            Text("Search Result!")
        }
    }
}
```

Then I called the function from here:

```kotlin
private fun updateContent() {
    setContent {
        ChemistryAssistantTheme {
            // A surface container using the 'background' color from the theme
            Surface(
                modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
                color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.background
            ) {
                Column() {
                    Title(" Chemistry Assistant ", " Made by Saket Tamrakar ")

                    Column() {
                        SearchElements()
                        SearchResult() // Here

                        //Options()
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The issue here is that the function gets correctly called in the beginning, when I invoke `updateContent()` here:

```kotlin
OutlinedTextField(value = input, placeholder = { Text("Search for any element!") }, onValueChange = {
    input = it
    searchInput = it.text

    updateContent()
})
```

Control does reach the function (at least according to what the debugger tells me), but still fails to execute the function body.

**Any ideas?**

Answer (score 1):

You should keep `searchInput` as a state like:
`val searchInput by mutableStateOf("")`

This ensures that whenever the value of searchInput changes, any composable whose structure depends on it will also recompose(i.e recall the function).

Hope this solves your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently moving the variable `searchInput`:

```kotlin
@Composable
fun SearchResult() {
    if (/*this one*/searchInput.isNotEmpty()) {
        Column() {
            Text("Search Result!")
        }
    }
}
```

..inside the `MainActivity` class fixed the issue.